# Find a weak solution of $- \Delta u + u = h(x) |u|^{q - 2}u$ in $\Bbb{R}^N$, $u \in H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$ - Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: solution-verification, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations, partial-differential-equations

The following is a problem in a text on Critical Point Theory (in Portuguese) I am reading. I would like to know if my reasoning is correct.

One observation: the Ekeland Variational Principle cited in the statement of the problem is only used to ascertain that a Palais-Smale sequence exists.

**The problem:**

> Use the Ekeland Variational Principle to solve the following sublinear problem:
>   $$
> (P) \quad
> \begin{cases}
> - \Delta u + u = h(x)|u|^{q - 2}u \quad \text{ in } \Bbb{R}^N, \\
> u \in H^1(\Bbb{R}^N),
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $1 < q < 2$, $h \in L^{\frac{2^*}{2^* - q}}(\Bbb{R}^N) \cap L^\infty(\Bbb{R}^N)$, $h \geq 0$, $h \neq 0$.

**My solution**:
The weak solutions for the problem $(P)$ are the critical points of the functional
$$
I(u) = \frac12 ||u||^2 - \frac{1}{q} \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} h(x) |u|^q \ dx,
$$
where $||u|| = (||\nabla u||_2^2 + ||u||_2^2)^{1/2}$ is the norm in $H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$. Also, $I$ is coercive and weakly lower semicontinuous, hence bounded from below.

Consider a Palais-Smale sequence at the level of the infimum of the functional, that is, $(u_n) \subset H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$ such that 
$$
I(u_n) \to c = \inf_{H^1(\Bbb{R}^N)}I, \quad I'(u_n) \to 0.
$$
Such a sequence exists by the Ekeland Variational Principle. Then $(u_n)$ is bounded, up to a subsequence. Otherwise we would have $I(u_n) \to \infty$, a contradiction. Therefore, since $H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$ is reflexive, there exists $u \in H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$ such that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$, up to a subsequence. Let us show that $u$ is a critical point.

Let $\phi \in C_c^\infty (\Bbb{R}^N)$. Then, by the compact Sobolev embeddings, 
$$
u_n|_{\text{supp} \phi} \to u|_{\text{supp} \phi} \quad \text{ in } L^s(\Bbb{R}^N),  
$$
for $s \in [1, 2^*)$, up to a subsequence. By Vainberg's Theorem there is a subsequence, again denoted $(u_n)$, and $g \in L^s(\text{supp} \phi)$ such that 
$$
u_n(x) \to u(x) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \text{supp} \phi
$$
and
$$
|u_n(x)| \leq g(x) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \text{supp} \phi.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
h(x)|u_n(x)|^{q - 2}u_n(x) \phi(x) \to h(x)|u(x)|^{q - 2}u(x) \phi(x) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \Bbb{R}^N
$$
and 
$$
h(x) |u_n(x)|^{q - 2}u_n(x) \phi(x) \leq h(x) g^{q - 1}(x) \phi(x) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \Bbb{R}^N.
$$ 
Note that $hg^{q - 1}\phi \in L^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)$. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, 
$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}^N} h(x) |u_n|^{q - 2}u_n \phi \ dx \to \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} h(x) |u|^{q - 2}u \phi \ dx.
$$
Also, note that 
$$
v \mapsto \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} \nabla v \cdot \nabla \phi \ dx + \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} v \phi \ dx
$$
is a continuous linear functional on $W^{1, p}(\Bbb{R}^N)$. Therefore, by the weak convergence,
$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}^N} \nabla u_n \cdot \nabla \phi \ dx + \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} u_n \phi \ dx \to \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \ dx + \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} u \phi \ dx.
$$

Since $I'(u_n) \to 0$, it follows that 
$$
0 = \lim I(u_n) \phi = I'(u)\phi.
$$This holds for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty (\Bbb{R}^N)$. By density, 
$$
I'(u)v = 0 \quad \forall v \in H^1(\Bbb{R}^N),
$$
and therefore $u$ is a weak solution of $(P)$.

Let $\phi \in C_c^\infty (\Bbb{R}^N)$, $\phi > 0$. Then
$$
I(t \psi) = \frac{t^2}{2}||\psi||^2 - \frac{t^q}{q} \int_{\Bbb{R}^N} h(x)|\psi|^q \ dx \leq 0 
$$
it $t$ is sufficiently small. Since $I(u) \leq I(t \psi)$, $u$ is not the trivial solution.

**My question**:

> Is the above correct?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.